# Plugin registered on Delete : Unable to deserialize the serialized value

Tags: serialization, plugins, dynamics-crm-2015

I've registered my plugin on Create, Update and Delete. It's working fine on the Create and Update messages but for the Delete I debugged the plugin code using visual studio and it's throwing exceptions even before the plugin code executes in Visual Studio.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to deserialize the serialized value.
>      at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ServiceWrappers.ExecutionContextWrapper.Deserialize(OperationType operation, String serializedValue)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.AppDomainProxy.Execute(ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration, ProfilerExecutionReport report)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.AppDomainProxy.Execute(ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration, ProfilerExecutionReport report)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionEngine.Execute(ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionUtility.Execute(PluginPermissions permissions, ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionUtility.Execute(PluginPermissions permissions, OperationConfiguration operation, ProfilerReportingConfiguration reporting, CrmServiceClient administratorProxy, ITracingService tracing)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.DebugPlugin.DebugPluginViewModel.btnExecutionClicked()
>   Inner Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 485. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts:ConcurrencyBehavior'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'ConcurrencyBehavior' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts'.
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeWithSurrogate(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract surrogateDataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
>      at ReadKeyValuePairFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeWithSurrogate(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract surrogateDataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
>      at ReadParameterCollectionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeWithSurrogate(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract surrogateDataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
>      at ReadPluginExecutionContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeWithSurrogate(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract surrogateDataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
>      at ReadPluginExecutionContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeWithSurrogate(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract surrogateDataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
>      at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PartialTrustSerializer.Deserialize(Type type, Byte[] value, Assembly proxyTypesAssembly)
>      at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PartialTrustSerializer.Deserialize(Type type, String value, Assembly proxyTypesAssembly)
>      at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ServiceWrappers.ExecutionContextWrapper.Deserialize(OperationType operation, String serializedValue)

Comment: How is the plugin registered exactly, also try rebuilding your early bound types.

Comment: @JamesWood, I've registered the plugin using the SDK 2015 plugin registration tool. It's isolation mode is "Sandbox". I've also updated my target framework to 4.5.2 but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I'm receiving this message in the Plugin Registeration tool.

Comment: pre/post? Also would help if you post some code.

Comment: Is it as easy that you are casting the target as an Entity and it's an EntityReference for delete?